# To pass an object to an another webservice

Tags: java, web-services, rest

I have a webservice and from this webservice I should pass an obejct to an another service. I tried with @Pathparam and @QueryParam but Iam not getting the values in my service.

The code where I am passing the object is

```
public void MediatorCmpService() {
    ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
    Client client = Client.create(config);
    WebResource service = client.resource(getBaseURI()); 
    boolean flag = validateConfig(iFGetResponse);

    if (flag) {
        CustomerData customerData = transformationPayload(iFGetResponse);
        TrilliumxmlProducer tri=new TrilliumxmlProducer(customerData);
    }
    System.out.println(flag);
}
```

Here I am passing the customerData Object to my TrilliumxmlProducer Service. But this Object is not getting passed to the TrilliumxmlProducer service

The code for the TrilliumxmlProducer is

```
@Path("/generateTrillium")
public class TrilliumxmlProducer {
    // This method is called if XMLis request
    public TrilliumxmlProducer(CustomerData customerData) throws JAXBException {

        getXML(customerData);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @GET
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
    public CustomerData getXML(@QueryParam("customerData") CustomerData customerData) throws JAXBException {
        System.out.println("--------2----------" + customerData.getREQUESTTYPE());

        return customerData;
    }
}
```

Here My object is giving nullpointer exception. Can anyone help me here

Answer (score 0):

You do not seem to be passing a QueryParameter in your request.

A PathParam is used to extract data from the Path, ie "endpoint/{id}/help" then the PathParam "id" would return whatever is in between "endpoint/" and "/help".

A QueryParam is used to extract data from the Query, ie "endpoint/help?id=" then the QueryParam would return whatever you have instead of  in youe request.

Although technically legal, you should try to avoid mixing and matching, and just use one or the other.

**Edit**

Also, while I'm not certain, I'm pretty confident that you can't/shouldn't use an object graph to pass around your rest resources.

Comment: Thanks for your reply So Whether can I pass that object directly to the service method ie in the service method can i Accept that as public CustomerData getXML(CustomerData customerData)

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do. If you want to pass an object, you should do so in JSON or XML (in the request body), using POST (for Create) or PUT (for Update). RESTFul webservices generally only use GET for Retrieve / Read operations.